# Print all inherited class member variables and methods

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, gdb

Suppose I have inheritance like below:

```
class A
{
public:
A(){}
int s;
void Show(){}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
B(){}
int y;
void MyShow() {}
};

int main()
{
B b;
}
```

Is there a way that I can know by any mechanism [runtime/debug] etc what are the member variables / methods of object `b` - I mean complete list along with all it inherited?

Comment: There is no direct way. You can serialize object to file with meaning full infomation. and then look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. C++ does not support reflection (the feature you'd need to be able to do this). You cannot iterate through an object and discover its members like in some other (dynamic) languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ptype` gdb command. However it will not print members of inherited type, you will have to do it yourself. Here you can print type `B`, note that it is inherited from type `A` and print `A` as well:

```
(gdb) ptype B
type = class B : public A {
  public:
    int y;

    B(void);
    void MyShow(void);
}
(gdb) ptype A
type = class A {
  public:
    int s;

    A(void);
    void Show(void);
}
(gdb)
```